# Does having local variables confined within methods make garbage collection easier?

Tags: java, android, memory, methods, garbage-collection

I am trying to optimise my code, memory wise, for an Android project I'm working on.

I am looking for a way to minimise the accumulated garbage, my main question would be is it worth injecting (through dagger) variables within a class, if they are to be used just within a specific method (either initialisation or for another purpose) or should I only declare them within the respected method will increase garbage collection after this method is executed?

F.i. is there a case where we want the following case:

```
@Inject
Foo foo;

@Overrides
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this);
}


public void bar() {
       foo.bar();
}
```

instead of the one below (given that the object will only be used within the bar method)?

```
@Overrides
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


public void bar() {
       Foo foo = new Foo();
       foo.bar();
}
```

Isn't the second case more memory efficient, rendering the object ready for the garbage collector?

Last, is there any case where it would be recommended to use System.gc()?

Thank you!

Comment: See [In Android, Should not be use System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19361184/5221149)

Comment: As for the first question, I'm not following. Please edit the question and show example of what you mean.

Comment: You might want to tag this question with `android` as it's somewhat specific to that platform?

Comment: Thank you, both! It has been updaded. Andrea, thank you also for the article, basically I understand it as a general rule that "there is no recommended case for `System.gc()`". I'm not sure if there may be any exceptions.

Comment: In the second variant, you are constructing a new `Foo` instance every time `bar()` is invoked, but on the other hand, it can get garbage collected afterwards. In the first variant, only one `Foo` instance is created, but it won’t get garbage collected, even when `bar()` is never called again. The question is, what are the costs for constructing a `Foo` instance.